# How to re-arrange Python Pandas dataframe shifting col header to next row and re-name merged header

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python pandas data frame which looks like the following in excel table:

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NlB0.jpg)

I want it to look like the following using python.Have tried but not able to find the solution.Please help!!

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbiLD.jpg)

Comment: What did you try so far? How do you read the excel table to Pandas?

Comment: excel_file1 = 'filepath\\file.xlsx'  df1=pd.read_excel(excel_file1,sheet_name=0)..in this sheet the above problem exists...